# dnsutils points to public IP of client machine, not server

Tags: dns, ip, dig

I am logged in via SSH to a remote machine, which is a Raspberry Pi 4. I am trying to use `dnsutils` to extract the public IP of the remote machine. However, it is returning the public IP of the client machine that I am physically using. I am using a shell script to do this. The specific command that I am using is

```
public_ip="$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)"
```

I am using SSH via a Windows 11 machine. Not that it matters, but I am using the Visual Studio Code remote - SSH extension package. I have also tried SSH via Windows PowerShell and it's still returning the public IP of the client machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly unlikely opendns is discovering the IP address of your SSH client if you are executing `dig` on your remote machine.

The most likely thing is that your client's public IPv4 address is the same as your remote machine's public IPv4 address.  This would happen if the two are in the same physical location or otherwise on the same LAN (perhaps through a VPN).

This is due to [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) introduced in the late 1990s to slow down [IPv4 address exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion).  This means that your home or office router will take one IP address for the whole LAN and and make it appear as if everything on your LAN is just one machine with that single IP address.

---

Incase it isn't obvious to future readers, requesting `myip.opendns.com` from the DNS server `resolver1.opendns.com` (or any of the `resolver*.opendns.com` servers) will result in an A name DNS record with the DNS client's IP address as seen by the DNS server.